# PHP session_destroy() warning Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have this php script and I'm having problems destroying the session:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['id_client']) &&  isset($_POST['ok'])){
        session_destroy();
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

I get this warning:

> Warning: session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\template\nota\finalizare_nota_mobil.php on line 6

When I simply use...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

...it works. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Actually the second one works if I call it from another location (I should mention that I call the first script from a jQuery post)

EDIT2:
Kind of tracked the issue to the jQuery $.post, but I don't get why. Here is the code:

```
$.post("../template/nota/finalizare_nota_mobil.php",{ok:1}, function(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
    if(data==1){
        alert("Total: "+totalPartial);
        window.location.href="http://qr-menu.ro/";
    }
});
```

Comment: What id you do not echo anything?

Comment: after the call to session_start(); try calling session_id() and let us know what you see - try echo session_id();

Comment: leej0qrdq5gsjg59no6oaqbgq6 . The session exists, because if i call the script from a diffrent location, it works

Comment: Marcell Fulpo, i read the post, no help whatsoever:(

Comment: Have you tried `session_restart()`?  Should be a simpler solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. The thing that i did was to empty the session and regenerate the id, then destroy it. I don't fully understand the problem, but it kinda does the job:

```
<?php    
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id_client']) &&  isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $_SESSION=array();
    session_regenerate_id(); 
    session_destroy();
    echo 1;
}
?>
```